# Consulta sql INNER JOIN com WHERE e GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Eu tenho essa consulta no meu banco de dados só que queria inserir uma soma no `a.preco_produto` e fazer por  `GROUP BY` só que se eu colocar `GROUP BY a.codigo_loja` nessa consulta da esse erro> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY lojas' at line 7

```
SELECT
a.codigo_loja_produto, a.codigo_loja, a.codigo_produto, b.nome_produto, b.codigo_barras, b.secoes_produtos, b.endereco_fotos,a.preco_produto,a.ultimo_preco, a.ultima_atualizacao
FROM loja_produto AS a
INNER JOIN  produtos AS b  on a.codigo_produto = b.cod_produto
INNER JOIN  lojas AS c on a.codigo_loja = c.cod_loja
WHERE a.codigo_loja = 3 Limit 20 OFFSET 0
GROUP BY a.codigo_loja
```

Comment: Pode colocar o `group by ` que está usando e qual o erro senão é difícil te ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário agrupar todas as colunas com tipos iguais.

Ex:

```
SELECT 
    a.codigo_loja_produto, 
    a.codigo_loja, 
    a.codigo_produto, 
    b.nome_produto, 
    b.codigo_barras, 
    b.secoes_produtos, 
    b.endereco_fotos,
    a.preco_produto,
    a.ultimo_preco, 
    a.ultima_atualizacao 
FROM loja_produto AS a 
    INNER JOIN produtos AS b ON a.codigo_produto = b.cod_produto 
    INNER JOIN lojas AS c ON a.codigo_loja = c.cod_loja 
WHERE a.codigo_loja = 3 
GROUP BY 
    a.codigo_loja_produto, 
    a.codigo_loja 
LIMIT 20 
OFFSET 0`
```

Levando em conta que o código loja produto e código loja contém registros iguais, para fazer isso deverá inserir todas as colunas que tem registro idêntico.

Comment: Valeu é isso ai mesmo